# Memory leak when using Spring.Collections.IMultiMap<TKey, TValue>

Tags: delphi, spring4d

Does anyone else have a problem with memory leaks when using Spring4D framework and `IMultiMap<TKye, TValue>` collections?

I use the last released version from the master branch (1.2.6), and when I use the `ForEach(Action<T>)` method, it generates a memory leak.

My collection is `IMultiMap<Integer, string>`. Here is an example:

```pascal
for var Id in AMultiMap.Keys do
begin
  var sComposeValues := string.Empty;
  AMultiMap.Items[Id].ForEach(
    procedure(const AValue: string)
    begin
      if (sComposeValues.IsEmpty) then
      begin
        sComposeValues := string.Format('(%s)', [AValue]);
      end
      else
      begin
        sComposeValues := string.Format('%s and (%s)', [sComposeValues, AValue]);
      end;
    end
    );

  DoSomethin(sComposeValues);
end;
```

If I use a `for..in` loop, there is no memory leak:

```pascal
for var Id in AMultiMap.Keys do
begin
  var sComposeValues := string.Empty;
  for var sValue in AMultiMap.Items[Id] do
  begin
    if (sComposeValues.IsEmpty) then
    begin
      sComposeValues := string.Format('(%s)', [sValue]);
    end
    else
    begin
      sComposeValues := string.Format('%s and (%s)', [sComposeValues, sValue]);
    end;
  end;
  
  DoSomethin(sComposeValues);
end;
```

```
Edit:
```

I make some changes to code and now there is no memory leak. It's all about where I define inline variable `sComposeValues`. Here is my quick MCVE:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    btn1: TBitBtn;
    mmo: TMemo;
    procedure btnClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure InitMultiMap(const AMultiMap: IMultiMap<System.Integer, string>);

    procedure FillByForEach(const AMultiMap: IMultiMap<System.Integer, string>; const AList: TStrings);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.btnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  var mmList := TCollections.CreateMultiMap<System.Integer, string>();
  Self.InitMultiMap(mmList);
  Self.FillByForEach(mmList, mmo.Lines);
end;

procedure TForm1.FillByForEach(const AMultiMap: IMultiMap<System.Integer, string>; const AList: TStrings);
begin
  AList.Clear();
  var sComposeValues: string; /// define inline before loop iteration - NO memory leak
  for var Id in AMultiMap.Keys do
  begin
    //var sComposeValues := string.Empty; ///define inline variable in for every iteration - HAS memory leak
    sComposeValues := string.Empty; // skip line if inline variable is define within loop
    AMultiMap.Items[Id].ForEach(
      procedure(const AValue: string)
      begin
        if (sComposeValues.IsEmpty) then
        begin
          sComposeValues := string.Format('(%s)', [AValue]);
        end
        else
        begin
          sComposeValues := string.Format('%s and (%s)', [sComposeValues, AValue]);
        end;
      end
    );

    AList.Add(sComposeValues);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.InitMultiMap(const AMultiMap: IMultiMap<System.Integer, string>);
begin
  AMultiMap.Clear();
  for var i := 1 to 5 do
  begin
    for var j := 1 to 5 do
    begin
      AMultiMap.Add(i, string.Format('ValueId_%d=%d', [i,j+10]));
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

There is five(5) iterations and it's left `4 X UnicodeString` blocks. It frees memory only from last iteration from TKye. Here is leak report:

```
--------------------------------2023/7/20 9:42:45--------------------------------
A memory block has been leaked. The size is: 212

This block was allocated by thread 0x4D5C, and the stack trace (return addresses) at the time was:
257212 [System.pas][System][@GetMem$qqri][4949]
25A5D3 [System.pas][System][@NewUnicodeString$qqri][26005]
25A814 [System.pas][System][@UStrFromPWCharLen$qqrr20System.UnicodeStringpbi][26617]
27AE10 [System.SysUtils.pas][System.SysUtils][Sysutils.FmtStr$qqrr20System.UnicodeStringx20System.UnicodeStringpx14System.TVarRecxirx31System.Sysutils.TFormatSettings][13001]
74B0B9B8 [Unknown function at LoadCursorW]
F32D29D 
774416FC [ZwAllocateVirtualMemory]
F32D2A4 
F30D7E9 
F307201 
F307212 

The block is currently used for an object of class: UnicodeString

The allocation number is: 1295

Current memory dump of 256 bytes starting at pointer address 7FC20DC0:
B0 04 02 00 01 00 00 00 5A 00 00 00 28 00 56 00 61 00 6C 00 75 00 65 00 49 00 64 00 5F 00 32 00
3D 00 31 00 31 00 29 00 20 00 61 00 6E 00 64 00 20 00 28 00 56 00 61 00 6C 00 75 00 65 00 49 00
64 00 5F 00 32 00 3D 00 31 00 32 00 29 00 20 00 61 00 6E 00 64 00 20 00 28 00 56 00 61 00 6C 00
75 00 65 00 49 00 64 00 5F 00 32 00 3D 00 31 00 33 00 29 00 20 00 61 00 6E 00 64 00 20 00 28 00
56 00 61 00 6C 00 75 00 65 00 49 00 64 00 5F 00 32 00 3D 00 31 00 34 00 29 00 20 00 61 00 6E 00
64 00 20 00 28 00 56 00 61 00 6C 00 75 00 65 00 49 00 64 00 5F 00 32 00 3D 00 31 00 35 00 29 00
00 00 74 70 92 47 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 00 00 00 00 60 0A C2 7F
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 24 8F 26 00 00 00 00 00 16 05 00 00 12 72 25 00 D3 A5 25 00 14 A8 25 00
°  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  Z  .  .  .  (  .  V  .  a  .  l  .  u  .  e  .  I  .  d  .  _  .  2  .
=  .  1  .  1  .  )  .     .  a  .  n  .  d  .     .  (  .  V  .  a  .  l  .  u  .  e  .  I  .
d  .  _  .  2  .  =  .  1  .  2  .  )  .     .  a  .  n  .  d  .     .  (  .  V  .  a  .  l  .
u  .  e  .  I  .  d  .  _  .  2  .  =  .  1  .  3  .  )  .     .  a  .  n  .  d  .     .  (  .
V  .  a  .  l  .  u  .  e  .  I  .  d  .  _  .  2  .  =  .  1  .  4  .  )  .     .  a  .  n  .
d  .     .  (  .  V  .  a  .  l  .  u  .  e  .  I  .  d  .  _  .  2  .  =  .  1  .  5  .  )  .
.  .  t  p  ’  G  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  .  .  .  .  `  .  В  
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  $  Џ  &  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  r  %  .  У  Ґ  %  .  .  Ё  %  .

--------------------------------2023/7/20 9:42:45--------------------------------
A memory block has been leaked. The size is: 212

This block was allocated by thread 0x4D5C, and the stack trace (return addresses) at the time was:
257212 [System.pas][System][@GetMem$qqri][4949]
25A5D3 [System.pas][System][@NewUnicodeString$qqri][26005]
25A814 [System.pas][System][@UStrFromPWCharLen$qqrr20System.UnicodeStringpbi][26617]
27AE10 [System.SysUtils.pas][System.SysUtils][Sysutils.FmtStr$qqrr20System.UnicodeStringx20System.UnicodeStringpx14System.TVarRecxirx31System.Sysutils.TFormatSettings][13001]
74B0B9B8 [Unknown function at LoadCursorW]
F32D29D 
774416FC [ZwAllocateVirtualMemory]
F32D2A4 
F30D7E9 
F307201 
F307212 

The block is currently used for an object of class: UnicodeString

The allocation number is: 1302

Current memory dump of 256 bytes starting at pointer address 7FC20F20:
B0 04 02 00 01 00 00 00 5A 00 00 00 28 00 56 00 61 00 6C 00 75 00 65 00 49 00 64 00 5F 00 35 00
3D 00 31 00 31 00 29 00 20 00 61 00 6E 00 64 00 20 00 28 00 56 00 61 00 6C 00 75 00 65 00 49 00
64 00 5F 00 35 00 3D 00 31 00 32 00 29 00 20 00 61 00 6E 00 64 00 20 00 28 00 56 00 61 00 6C 00
75 00 65 00 49 00 64 00 5F 00 35 00 3D 00 31 00 33 00 29 00 20 00 61 00 6E 00 64 00 20 00 28 00
56 00 61 00 6C 00 75 00 65 00 49 00 64 00 5F 00 35 00 3D 00 31 00 34 00 29 00 20 00 61 00 6E 00
64 00 20 00 28 00 56 00 61 00 6C 00 75 00 65 00 49 00 64 00 5F 00 35 00 3D 00 31 00 35 00 29 00
00 00 70 37 24 45 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 00 00 00 00 60 0A C2 7F
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 24 8F 26 00 00 00 00 00 1D 05 00 00 12 72 25 00 D3 A5 25 00 14 A8 25 00
°  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  Z  .  .  .  (  .  V  .  a  .  l  .  u  .  e  .  I  .  d  .  _  .  5  .
=  .  1  .  1  .  )  .     .  a  .  n  .  d  .     .  (  .  V  .  a  .  l  .  u  .  e  .  I  .
d  .  _  .  5  .  =  .  1  .  2  .  )  .     .  a  .  n  .  d  .     .  (  .  V  .  a  .  l  .
u  .  e  .  I  .  d  .  _  .  5  .  =  .  1  .  3  .  )  .     .  a  .  n  .  d  .     .  (  .
V  .  a  .  l  .  u  .  e  .  I  .  d  .  _  .  5  .  =  .  1  .  4  .  )  .     .  a  .  n  .
d  .     .  (  .  V  .  a  .  l  .  u  .  e  .  I  .  d  .  _  .  5  .  =  .  1  .  5  .  )  .
.  .  p  7  $  E  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  .  .  .  .  `  .  В  
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  $  Џ  &  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  r  %  .  У  Ґ  %  .  .  Ё  %  .

--------------------------------2023/7/20 9:42:45--------------------------------
A memory block has been leaked. The size is: 212

This block was allocated by thread 0x4D5C, and the stack trace (return addresses) at the time was:
257212 [System.pas][System][@GetMem$qqri][4949]
25A5D3 [System.pas][System][@NewUnicodeString$qqri][26005]
25A814 [System.pas][System][@UStrFromPWCharLen$qqrr20System.UnicodeStringpbi][26617]
27AE10 [System.SysUtils.pas][System.SysUtils][Sysutils.FmtStr$qqrr20System.UnicodeStringx20System.UnicodeStringpx14System.TVarRecxirx31System.Sysutils.TFormatSettings][13001]
74B0B9B8 [Unknown function at LoadCursorW]
F32D29D 
774416FC [ZwAllocateVirtualMemory]
F32D2A4 
F30D7E9 
F307201 
F307212 

The block is currently used for an object of class: UnicodeString

The allocation number is: 1309

Current memory dump of 256 bytes starting at pointer address 7FC21080:
B0 04 02 00 01 00 00 00 5A 00 00 00 28 00 56 00 61 00 6C 00 75 00 65 00 49 00 64 00 5F 00 34 00
3D 00 31 00 31 00 29 00 20 00 61 00 6E 00 64 00 20 00 28 00 56 00 61 00 6C 00 75 00 65 00 49 00
64 00 5F 00 34 00 3D 00 31 00 32 00 29 00 20 00 61 00 6E 00 64 00 20 00 28 00 56 00 61 00 6C 00
75 00 65 00 49 00 64 00 5F 00 34 00 3D 00 31 00 33 00 29 00 20 00 61 00 6E 00 64 00 20 00 28 00
56 00 61 00 6C 00 75 00 65 00 49 00 64 00 5F 00 34 00 3D 00 31 00 34 00 29 00 20 00 61 00 6E 00
64 00 20 00 28 00 56 00 61 00 6C 00 75 00 65 00 49 00 64 00 5F 00 34 00 3D 00 31 00 35 00 29 00
00 00 09 36 24 45 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 00 00 00 00 60 0A C2 7F
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 24 8F 26 00 00 00 00 00 24 05 00 00 12 72 25 00 D3 A5 25 00 14 A8 25 00
°  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  Z  .  .  .  (  .  V  .  a  .  l  .  u  .  e  .  I  .  d  .  _  .  4  .
=  .  1  .  1  .  )  .     .  a  .  n  .  d  .     .  (  .  V  .  a  .  l  .  u  .  e  .  I  .
d  .  _  .  4  .  =  .  1  .  2  .  )  .     .  a  .  n  .  d  .     .  (  .  V  .  a  .  l  .
u  .  e  .  I  .  d  .  _  .  4  .  =  .  1  .  3  .  )  .     .  a  .  n  .  d  .     .  (  .
V  .  a  .  l  .  u  .  e  .  I  .  d  .  _  .  4  .  =  .  1  .  4  .  )  .     .  a  .  n  .
d  .     .  (  .  V  .  a  .  l  .  u  .  e  .  I  .  d  .  _  .  4  .  =  .  1  .  5  .  )  .
.  .  .  6  $  E  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  .  .  .  .  `  .  В  
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  $  Џ  &  .  .  .  .  .  $  .  .  .  .  r  %  .  У  Ґ  %  .  .  Ё  %  .

--------------------------------2023/7/20 9:42:45--------------------------------
A memory block has been leaked. The size is: 212

This block was allocated by thread 0x4D5C, and the stack trace (return addresses) at the time was:
257212 [System.pas][System][@GetMem$qqri][4949]
25A5D3 [System.pas][System][@NewUnicodeString$qqri][26005]
25A814 [System.pas][System][@UStrFromPWCharLen$qqrr20System.UnicodeStringpbi][26617]
27AE10 [System.SysUtils.pas][System.SysUtils][Sysutils.FmtStr$qqrr20System.UnicodeStringx20System.UnicodeStringpx14System.TVarRecxirx31System.Sysutils.TFormatSettings][13001]
74B0B9B8 [Unknown function at LoadCursorW]
F32D29D 
774416FC [ZwAllocateVirtualMemory]
F32D2A4 
F30D7E9 
F307201 
F307212 

The block is currently used for an object of class: UnicodeString

The allocation number is: 1316

Current memory dump of 256 bytes starting at pointer address 7FC211E0:
B0 04 02 00 01 00 00 00 5A 00 00 00 28 00 56 00 61 00 6C 00 75 00 65 00 49 00 64 00 5F 00 31 00
3D 00 31 00 31 00 29 00 20 00 61 00 6E 00 64 00 20 00 28 00 56 00 61 00 6C 00 75 00 65 00 49 00
64 00 5F 00 31 00 3D 00 31 00 32 00 29 00 20 00 61 00 6E 00 64 00 20 00 28 00 56 00 61 00 6C 00
75 00 65 00 49 00 64 00 5F 00 31 00 3D 00 31 00 33 00 29 00 20 00 61 00 6E 00 64 00 20 00 28 00
56 00 61 00 6C 00 75 00 65 00 49 00 64 00 5F 00 31 00 3D 00 31 00 34 00 29 00 20 00 61 00 6E 00
64 00 20 00 28 00 56 00 61 00 6C 00 75 00 65 00 49 00 64 00 5F 00 31 00 3D 00 31 00 35 00 29 00
00 00 A2 34 24 45 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 00 00 00 00 21 14 C2 7F
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 2B 05 00 00 12 72 25 00 D3 A5 25 00 14 A8 25 00
°  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  Z  .  .  .  (  .  V  .  a  .  l  .  u  .  e  .  I  .  d  .  _  .  1  .
=  .  1  .  1  .  )  .     .  a  .  n  .  d  .     .  (  .  V  .  a  .  l  .  u  .  e  .  I  .
d  .  _  .  1  .  =  .  1  .  2  .  )  .     .  a  .  n  .  d  .     .  (  .  V  .  a  .  l  .
u  .  e  .  I  .  d  .  _  .  1  .  =  .  1  .  3  .  )  .     .  a  .  n  .  d  .     .  (  .
V  .  a  .  l  .  u  .  e  .  I  .  d  .  _  .  1  .  =  .  1  .  4  .  )  .     .  a  .  n  .
d  .     .  (  .  V  .  a  .  l  .  u  .  e  .  I  .  d  .  _  .  1  .  =  .  1  .  5  .  )  .
.  .  ў  4  $  E  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  Ђ  .  .  .  .  !  .  В  
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  +  .  .  .  .  r  %  .  У  Ґ  %  .  .  Ё  %  .

--------------------------------2023/7/20 9:42:45--------------------------------
This application has leaked memory. The small block leaks are (excluding expected leaks registered by pointer):

181 - 212 bytes: UnicodeString x 4

Note: Memory leak detail is logged to a text file in the same folder as this application. To disable this memory leak check, undefine "EnableMemoryLeakReporting".
```

After update to `develop` branch and rebuild Spring4D framework there is still memory leak when use inline variable `sComposeValues` in `.Keys` iterations. It still allocate memory for variable for every scope, but did no free on the end of scope, this happens only for last scope.

Comment: Can you show an MCVE and include the leak report. Also, that branch is so old now. The collection code is massively changed and improved on develop.

Comment: Is it stable to use develop branch. I was waiting for official 2.0 release, but may be I must switch to develop branch and use it.

Comment: I'm not sure why Stefan hasn't released off develop yet. I was involved with some of the development of the new collections and sorting code, but it was years ago now. I guess only Stefan could answer your question.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Spring4d but with https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-34818

Comment: Yes, after some test I found than this has nothing with Spring4D.